# Control key based hotstring

Tags: autohotkey

How can I define a hotstring (not hotkey) which starts with a Control key pressed and released and then another key pressed?

E.g. I want action to be triggered after I press and release control and then press 'A'. Ctrl-A should not be intercepted by Autohotkey.

Answer (score -1):

1:

If You want to Use a Hotstring to send a Control pressed and released and then Press a Key.

You can try this Code.

If you type hotstringexample, then it will Execute the Code. (select all)

```
:*:hotstringexample:: 
send {Ctrl Down}a{Ctrl Up}
return
```

2:

And if you want to be triggered after you did press and release the control key,

so that you then can **press a to send a** or **press a to send Ctrl + a**

If you want to use the **Ctrl key** as a **Ctrl Lock** or **Ctrl Unlock**

You can Try this Code.

```
;Press the Ctrl key to Switch between Control Lock and Control Unlock

a := 0 

Ctrl up::

if (a = 0)
{
send {ctrl down}
a = 1
MsgBox the Crtl is Now Locked - if you now press a it will Do press Ctrl+a
} else {
send {ctrl up}
a = 0
MsgBox the Crtl is Now UnLocked - if you now press a it will Do press a
}
return
```

Note : You can Delete the MsgBox Codelines, this is only to use for explanation.